# Tflite Object detection android app with custom dataset Crash immediately after running

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, tflite

I tried to run object detection TensorFlow lite with a custom dataset but I got these errors. After training my dataset and converting it to .tflite format and metadata I put it in the asserts folder directly and run the app but it will close immediately. I tried different model but same error I would be appreciate if help me

```
2022-08-05 00:22:33.846 5758-5758/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection, PID: 5758
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: mobilenetv1.tflite
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAssetFd(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:950)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromFdAndOptions(TaskJniUtils.java:65)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.createFromFileAndOptions(ObjectDetector.java:147)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection.ObjectDetectorHelper.setupObjectDetector(ObjectDetectorHelper.kt:96)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection.ObjectDetectorHelper.<init>(ObjectDetectorHelper.kt:45)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection.ObjectDetectorHelper.<init>(ObjectDetectorHelper.kt:30)
    at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.objectdetection.fragments.CameraFragment.onViewCreated(CameraFragment.kt:98)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3030)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:589)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:300)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1647)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3128)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:262)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:510)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8231)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3872)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
```

Answer (score 1):

You got a FileNotFoundException, you should debug and check for the cause. But it should be useful if you post the code causing the problem here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will provide my cod 

aaptOptions {
         noCompress "tflite"
         noCompress "pb"